# Prove the existence of other "Triplet Primes"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The sequence 3,5,7 is a list of three prime numbers such that each pair of adjacent numbers in the list differ by two. Are there any more such "triplet pairs"? (Not homework)

Comment: Any triplet of numbers $(n,n+2,n+4)$ has exactly one term divisible by $3$, so no.

Comment: Sorry, but why is exactly one term divisible by 3?

Comment: I don't know any formula for a prime number than I can substitute for n that I could factor a 3 out of n, n+2, n+4.

Comment: Think about remainders when dividing by 3. The remainders can only be 1 or 2 in order NOT to be divisible by 3, hence Florence's answer

Comment: Consider the cases of $n \bmod 3$.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 6):

(posting as an answer)

Any triplet of numbers $(n,n+2,n+4)$ has exactly one term divisible by $3$, so no. If $n$ is divisible by three, then we're done. If $n$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $3$, then $n = 3k+1$, so $n+2 = 3k+3=3(k+1)$. If $n$ has remainder $2$ when divided by $3$, then $n = 3k+2$, and $n+4 = 3k+6 = 3(k+2)$.